# Extracting range of unpadded string

Tags: swift, regex

I'd like to extract the `Range<String.Index>` of a sentence within its whitespace padding. For example,

```
let padded = "    El águila ().  " 
let sentenceRangeInPadded = ???
assert(padded[sentenceRangeInPadded] == "El águila ().") // The test!
```

Here's some regex that I started with, but looks like variable length lookbehinds aren't supported.

```
let sentenceRangeInPadded = padded.range(of: #"(?<=^\s*).*?(?=\s*$)"#, options: .regularExpression)!
```

I'm not looking to extract the sentence (could just use `trimmingCharacters(in:)` for that), just the `Range`.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `guard let start = padded.firstIndex(where: { !$0.isWhitespace }),
    let end = padded.lastIndex(where: { !$0.isWhitespace })
    else {
        fatalError()
}
print(padded[start...end] == "El águila ().")`

Comment: `let trimmed = padded.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
if let rg = padded.range(of: trimmed) {
    print(padded[rg])
}`

Comment: @ielyamani Your first comment does the trick. Simple and readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
#"(?s)\S(?:.*\S)?"#
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IwBbSF/1/).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier making `.` match any char, including line break chars
- `\S` - the first non-whitespace char
- `(?:.*\S)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
  - `\S` - up to the last non-whitespace char.

Comment: Thanks for this. The explanation was very helpful too. So much to learn about regex!